# Rails date field not removing date when updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, date, casting

I have a form with a text field for inputting a date:

```
<%= f.text_field :my_date %>
```

If I input a date into this field, click submit and then go back to the form again and remove the date value that I've just entered (with no validation applied) the form saves but the original date is still there. I can't get rid of it once I've entered and saved it.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because it is a virtual attribute and needed to use `""` if it thought it was `nil`